# Radio buttons can't be clicked on tkinter/python app

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code which sets up some button and radio buttons. The radio buttons (Full Tcl version info: 8.6.11) can not be clicked on my side (Python 3.9.2 on Debian Linux 11):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ComplexGUIExample(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Complex GUI Example")
        self.geometry("400x300")

        # Frame for VPN controls
        vpn_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        vpn_frame.pack(pady=(10, 0), padx=(10, 0), fill=tk.X)

        # VPN Connection Button
        button_connect_vpn = tk.Button(vpn_frame, text="Connect VPN", command=self.dummy_command)
        button_connect_vpn.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(10, 10))

        # Check VPN Status Button
        button_check_vpn = tk.Button(vpn_frame, text="Check VPN Status", command=self.dummy_command)
        button_check_vpn.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(10, 10))

        # Frame for URL Loading Preferences (Radio Buttons)
        url_pref_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="URL Loading Preferences", padx=10, pady=10)
        url_pref_frame.pack(pady=(20, 0), padx=(10, 0), fill=tk.X)

        # Variable to track the radio button selection
        self.url_loading_preference = tk.StringVar(value="Most Recent")

        # Radio Buttons for URL Loading Preference
        tk.Radiobutton(url_pref_frame, text="Most Recent", variable=self.url_loading_preference, value="Most Recent", command=self.on_radio_change).pack(anchor=tk.W)
        tk.Radiobutton(url_pref_frame, text="Oldest", variable=self.url_loading_preference, value="Oldest", command=self.on_radio_change).pack(anchor=tk.W)
        tk.Radiobutton(url_pref_frame, text="Random page", variable=self.url_loading_preference, value="Random page", command=self.on_radio_change).pack(anchor=tk.W)

    def dummy_command(self):
        print("Button clicked")

    def on_radio_change(self):
        print(f"Selected URL Loading Preference: {self.url_loading_preference.get()}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ComplexGUIExample()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]

How do I make the radio buttons clickable ?

I have tried using some other widgets but so far I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Your code is working on my side  using 3.11.5, Debian  Linux 12

Comment: Your code is working in my system. Python version : Python 3.10.12 ; OS : Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `grid` method instead of `pack` for the radio buttons. The `grid` method allows you to specify the row and column where each widget should be placed, enabling them to be positioned side-by-side.

```
url_pref_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="URL Loading Preferences", padx=10, pady=10)
url_pref_frame.pack(pady=(20, 0), padx=(10, 0), fill=tk.X)

self.url_loading_preference = tk.StringVar(value="Most Recent")

row = 0  # Keep track of the current row for grid placement
tk.Radiobutton(url_pref_frame, text="Most Recent", variable=self.url_loading_preference, value="Most Recent", command=self.on_radio_change).grid(row=row, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
row += 1  
tk.Radiobutton(url_pref_frame, text="Oldest", variable=self.url_loading_preference, value="Oldest", command=self.on_radio_change).grid(row=row, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
row += 1  
tk.Radiobutton(url_pref_frame, text="Random page", variable=self.url_loading_preference, value="Random page", command=self.on_radio_change).grid(row=row, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
```

By using `grid` and specifying the row for each radio button, you ensure they are placed horizontally within the frame, making them all clickable.

[image: Working Code]

[image: Working code 2]

Comment: This makes no sense. OP can already make the buttons appear. Why would their *layout* have anything to do with whether they respond to being clicked?